# Matlab 2013a with raspberry pi model B+

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to interface my laptop using matlab to a raspberry pi board via a wifi connection. I am using MATLAB 2013a version and my raspberry board is model B+. 
I tried to establish the connection using the command

```
mypi = raspi
```

but it was showing error. Lateron i read that matlab 2014a was recently updated with raspberry model B+.

As i don't have the 2014 ver of matlab, is there any way to establish the connection to the board using matlab 2013a?

Comment: Can you elaborate what sort of connection are you looking for ? If you're looking for simulink rpi package, I'm afraid that package is available for matlab 14 and beyond. (Link : http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45145-matlab-support-package-for-raspberry-pi-hardware)

Comment: @dastaan i want to retrieve files from pi board to a laptop using wifi connection using matlab. I hope you got what am trying to do. I know Simulink rpi package are only available for 2014 and beyond. So is there any way to achieve my goal. The command 'raspi' wont work with matlab 2013a i guess. So is there a way to solve this issue.

Comment: If getting files is the objective, I would suggest scp or winscp over wifi to fetch files instead of matlab. But most likely that won't be a case. May be you can use a python script to download files from rpi over network and then use it in matlab as a workaround.

Comment: Actually i am trying to build an application where getting file is one of the objective of that application. So will that sound better ti use two languages for a single application

Comment: Well, I am no expert on Matlab but either you will have to upgrade to 14a or change your project platform entirely. If you're aiming at some image processing application (a wild guess from your past questions on this site), I would suggest you to look at OpenCV and other open source options. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
mypi=raspberrpi('ip','usrname','pass')
```

Example:

```
mypi=raspberrypi('192.168.100.7','pi','raspberry')
```